# Problem connecting via SSH to a Raspberry PI

Tags: ssh, raspbian-buster

When connecting to the Malina at the local address, everything works fine, but when connecting from outside writes:
Unable to negotiate with 46.250.28.77 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
Already tried everything. Can you help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnjMD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Command:

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc root@[YourIP]
```

And maybe censor your IP. Even if its not open to the world. :)